# Can removing non-alphanumeric characters prevent SQL Injection

Tags: sql, t-sql, security, sql-injection

Imagine a simple query:

```
Declare @sql varchar(100)
Declare @table varchar(20)
Set @table = 'foo'
select @sql = 'select * from ' + @table 
exec(@sql)
```

This would work okay until someone changes @table to be something like 'sys.tables; drop table bar'

However I am wondering if @table had all non alpha-numeric characters removed from it, could SQL injection still occur?  In this example the malicious @table would = 'systablesdroptablebar'.

Now I know using sp_executesql and parameterized SQL is the best practice. So don't give me any of that junk! I'm curious, how a string that removes all non alphanumeric characters could be compromised to deliver a SQL injection payload.

For clarity's sake this code block would be executed in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or greater.

Comment: separate to your explicit question but one thing to consider is to make sure the user account you're accessing your database with isn't granted too much privilege. For example you **don't** want to be using the `db_owner` role for a website account generally. You could create a user that only has `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` roles assigned to it. No `drop` statements can be ran then

Comment: That's a great point, in this case I'm working more on a utility that dev's will be using from within SQL Server, so as admins the privilege thing doesn't apply in our context.

Comment: Ah cool. With any external system (website,desktop app, api etc) I would always create a specific non-`db_owner` user. Just not worth the risk is it! :D

Answer (score 1):

*I don't have good examples of compromises for your case but I can tell you how I might attempt to defensively program against it...*

1. Consider Whitelisting table access
2. Maybe you can restrict the access to a specific subset of tables. Ideally, these tables follow a common naming scheme so the table name can be validated against that scheme.
3. If whitelisting the table names is not an option-- you could at least check whether the supplied table name is present in the database by querying the `sys.tables` system table.
4. For SQL Server, you should put the table name in square brackets

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [" + tableName + "]"`

This resource on SQL injection would thoroughly answer your question: [OWASP Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

Comment: can you expand on why I should wrap table name with []? What does it afford me?

Comment: @AndrewNieuwsma because it will cause an error. Suppose @table = 'users; drop table dbo.users;--' then the execution would be `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [users; drop table dbo.users;--' and thus, miss the closing bracket. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx as well

Comment: @AndrewNieuwsma Yeapers...Simon is correct. Injection will make the query error instead of executing...